# Create JSON object with multiple values inside an array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json, api

I am working with Acuity Scheduling API and in order to post a custom field, I need to have a JSON object inside of the array that has 2 key/pair values, id and value. Here is my current code for this:

```
 $postarray = array (
        'datetime'=>'2017-02-01T14:00:00-0800',         
        'appointmentTypeID'=>'Appt ID',
        'firstName'=>'First Name',
        'lastName'=>'last Name',
        'email'=>'myemail',
        'phone'=>'phone #',
        'fields' => array(
        array('id'=>'1234', 'value'=>'Field Data')
        )
);

$post = json_encode($postarray);
```

I have an array inside of the 'fields' array because I don't know how to add a json object with 2 values inside of an array that will then go through json_encode, as the request requires that it be converted to JSON first before being sent.

It is currently giving me this error: "{"status_code":400,"message":"The intake form field \u00221234\u0022 does not exist on this appointment." Where after "u0022" it adds on my field id. What I need is for my main array to become a JSON Object, the 'fields' to be an array, then the individual id and value pairs to be their own objects, like so (Taken Directly from Acuity Scheduling API):

```
 {
  "datetime": "2016-02-03T14:00:00-0800",
  "appointmentTypeID": 1,
  "firstName": "Bob",
  "lastName": "McTest",
  "email": "bob.mctest@example.com",
  "certificate": "ABC123",
  "fields": [
    {"id": 1, "value": "Party time!"}
  ]
}
```

Here is Acuity Scheduling API for reference on this particular request, https://developers.acuityscheduling.com/reference#post-appointments

Answer (score 0):

```
'fields' => array(
     json_encode(array('id'=>'1234', 'value'=>'Field Data'))
)
```

Comment: I don't see anything in the API documentation that says that this should be encoded as JSON.

Comment: The example he posted shows a JSON object nested within the JSON object. Calling json_encode around the array will create the json object within the json object.

Comment: There's no such thing as a "JSON object", it's a common misnomer. JSON is a format for representing arrays and objects as strings.

Comment: @Barmar When I tried to post the data to Acuity before encoding it, it said it needed to be in JSON format, that's how I knew.

Comment: @EricBrown The whole object needs to be in JSON format, but the elements inside it don't need to be doubly-encoded.

Comment: @EricBrown If they wanted `fields` to be a JSON string, it would look like `"fields": "[{\"id\": 1, \"value\": \"Some value\"}]"`

Comment: This answer unfortunately didn't work for me, just produced the same error.

Comment: Did you try casting the ID to int or removing the single quotes to make the ID an int?

Answer (score 0):

The ID should be a number, not a string, so don't put it in quotes.

```
$postarray = array (
    'datetime'=>'2017-02-01T14:00:00-0800',         
    'appointmentTypeID'=>'Appt ID',
    'firstName'=>'First Name',
    'lastName'=>'last Name',
    'email'=>'myemail',
    'phone'=>'phone #',
    'fields' => array(
        array('id'=> 1234, 'value'=>'Field Data')
    )
);
```

If you're getting the ID from a script parameter, use `intval()` to convert it from a string to a number.